# Inventory Management

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find about getting a script that when I put my part number and qty in  it adds to my list and when the wrong part number is entered it displays in error message that says invalid part number.

[image: spreadsheet screenshot]

I am not sure if i am on the right track. this is what I have currently.

```
function addQty() {
  var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ssheet.getSheetByName('List');
  var inputPartnum = ssheet.getRange("K2").getValue(); 
  var inputQty = ssheet.getRange("$L$2").getValue();
  var partNum1 = ssheet.getRange("I").getValue();

if (inputPartnum=partNum1){
  var num1 = ssheet.getRange("C").getValue();  
  ssheet.getRange("C").setValue(inputQty+num1); 
  ssheet.getRange('K2').clear();
  ssheet.getRange('L2').clear();
    }
  else {
    catch (error) {
        throw new Error( "Part Number Not Found" );
    ssheet.getRange('K2').clear();
    ssheet.getRange('L2').clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close. You need to loop through the part numbers looking for a match. Try this:

```
  function addQty() {
  var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ssheet.getSheetByName('List');
  var lr= sheet.getLastRow()
  var inputPartnum = sheet.getRange("K2").getValue().toLowerCase(); 
  var inputQty = sheet.getRange("$L$2").getValue();
  var partNum1 = sheet.getRange(6,9,lr,1).getValues();//Array of part numbers
  var count=0 //Set counter
  for(var i=0;i<partNum1.length;i++){ //Loop through part numbers
    if (inputPartnum == partNum1[i][0].toLowerCase()){
      var num1 = ssheet.getRange("C"+(i+6)).getValue(); //Get current part count 
      ssheet.getRange("C"+(i+6)).setValue(inputQty+num1); 
      count=count+1 //Add to count if a match is found
      ssheet.getRange('K2').clear();
      ssheet.getRange('L2').clear();
      break
  }}
  if(count==0){// If no matching part number is found give message.
     Browser.msgBox( "Part Number "+inputPartnum+" Not Found" );
     ssheet.getRange('K2').clear();
     ssheet.getRange('L2').clear();
  }}
```

I changed the script to get all the part numbers. If this is not what you are after, please explain what you are after.

Comment: I did not mark the line to add to the spreadsheet. please see the link below to see the spreadsheet. I need it to add to the qty column on the respective row.

https://docs.google.com/a/qualityplastics.com/spreadsheets/d/1cc5kUKpx24zygm1s3ollzFihYhlfMoTF0N67SxkaXEg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It is almost there. There seems to be some rouge numbers coming through. 

eg. cell C511, C528 this happens across the board also it is filling in the first line of each section with a quantity even if that was not entered

See the picture attached picture link.
https://www.screencast.com/t/gxM9pz8n5Gl

Comment: @JamesonSmith What link?

Comment: @JamesonSmith Those values are not from my script. Delete them and see of they appear again. Also, where are the totals coming from?

Comment: The totals are sums in the spreedsheet